# Snapshot view config spec load rules based on labels

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

I'm trying to create a snapshot view via perl script which is working fine. Currently trying to write a config spec that loads based on label for that view. Problem I'm facing is root directory doesnot have this label. so below config spec is falling. I can't add main/latest because I need files only with this label.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
load \vobname
element * labelname-nocheckout
element * -none
```

Comment: I see I have answered quite a few ClearCase questions for you without any comment, vote or accept tick. Were those older answers useful?

Comment: Thought I have accepted most of your answers, let me cross check again. Your input are helping me in great deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a rule *just* for the root directory `/vobname`:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /vobname /main/LATEST
element * labelname-nocheckout
element * -none 
load /vobname
```

A few comments:

- the load rule (load /vobname) can be set at the end of the config spec
- you don't need to use `\`, even on Windows. '`/`' is fine
- the order of the selection rule is important, which is why the `element /vobname /main/LATEST` is placed first.
- The selection rule `element /vobname /main/LATEST` is *only* for the folder `/vobname` (not for any of its sub-folder elements)
- this assumes that any element *under* /vobname has a label set on one of its versions.

Comment: ,what happens if  one of subdirectory does not have this label and file beneath got this label ?

Comment: @maestromani that folder won't be selected, meaning all its sub-elements won't be either. You would need to add a `element /vobname/myfolder /main/LATEST` rule before the `element * labelname` rule.

Comment: ,Looks like I have more problem now. Writing a script which will take two inputs(label name and vob name). This script would create a snapshot view, download files only with label (files and directory without label should be ignored) and make a tar out of it. Problem Current structure is vob--> sub directory--> sub directories --> files. Only files got label and not directories.

Comment: @maestromani your approach can *only* work if the label is applied *consistently* on *all* elements (files *and* folders) of the vob. That is why an UCM baseline translates into a label applied on *all* elements of a component.

Comment: What could be the solution for my case please ?

Comment: Create dynamic view and populate files with this label to another directory?

Comment: @maestromani this has nothing to do with the creation of the view (which you use to select and see those labelled versions). You need to know how the label is applied: what process does create that label? That process needs to apply that label on *all* files and folders, not just files. Then the solution I proposed in my answer will work.